# Since updating ROS a few hours ago, ROS/catkin is broken

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, ros-hydro, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

A couple of hours ago, I updated my system (sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade). Updates included a lot of Hydro updates as well. However since then, catkin_make always ends in an error. I tried:

- Reinstalling all ROS hydro packages
- Rebooting computer
- Create a new catkin ws and build the empty ws:
- `mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src`
- `cd ~/catkin_ws/src`
- `catkin_init_workspace`
- `cd ~/catkin_ws/`
- `catkin_make` -> this gives an error again.
- Commenting out all my ROS related stuff in .bashrc and try again with the new catkin ws in a new terminal

The relevant lines of the error seem to be (find full output of cmake_ here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sgw9whjn2cm91l8/catkin_make_error.txt):

```
CMake Error at /home/koenlek/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake:2 (message):
  Invalid package manifest
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_create/templates/qt-ros/package.xml":
  Package name "%(package)s does not follow naming conventions

  Invalid email %(author)s@gmail.com" for person "%(author)s""
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:36 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:63 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I checked the qt-ros and qt-create packages, it seems like nothing has changed in the last apt-get update (no changes on their github at least), so I think it is something else causing the issues.

Anybody has any ideas how to fix this? I need to perform some tests later today, so I badly need my system to get up and running again.

It seems that answers.ros.org is experiencing some spamming spree with loads of non-sense spambot messages coming in the latest hours. Is this some hacking/ddos attempt that has caused the servers to serve me some non-working updates?

I run Ubuntu 12.04 x64 with latest updates.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174736/since-updating-ros-a-few-hours-ago,-ros/catkin-is-broken/) by [koenlek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4402/koenlek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 432 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue here is that `catkin` is now finding the "template" package.xml in the python directory for `qt-create`. I don't know if this is because `qt-create` recently moved it or because of a change in `catkin`, but either way, there needs to be a `CATKIN_IGNORE` file as a peer to the `package.xml` file which is giving you problems, so that catkin doesn't try to parse it.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [koenlek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4402/koenlek/) on 2014-06-25**:
Thanks. Adding CATKIN_IGNORE solved it too (but more nicely than my old way). Posted a bug report here: https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros/issues/10